# Why aren't Atlas and P-Body good enough for GLaDOS? [Spoilers]

Tags: portal-2

GLaDOS's ultimate goal in this part of the game is to find all the hidden humans in Aperture Science to use for testing.

My question is, why did she feel she needed to do that?  After all, she had Atlas and P-Body to do the testing for her, so why would she need anybody else?

Comment: Because testing.

Comment: It's not science if there's no consequence for failure, after all.

Comment: Because science.

Comment: @Unionhawk +1 for the quote.

Comment: Maybe she got a new car, that is why she wants spoilers.

Comment: Well, they were composed of a single scientific calculator each...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We don't exactly know what GLaDOS is testing for.

However, from the events of Portal 1, we can guess she's testing how efficient humans are in solving puzzles when under psychological stress.

And indeed, she did put a lot of stress on Chell, such as:

- Telling her she'd die if she doesn't solve the puzzle.
- Claiming the chamber would not be monitored.
- Forcing her to murder [her only true friend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2OXA.png).
- Having her run through a live fire course designed for military androids.

None of which would truly matter for computers such as Atlas or P-Body, since they ultimately aren't human. If they die, they could just be rebuilt.

In the end, all of this is just a guess and we still don't know what exactly GLaDOS is testing for.

Answer (score -2):

She didn't make Atlas and Peabody until later on (in the second game I'm pretty sure while she was testing you). When Weatley mentions them she says something along the lines of "I made them to get rid of human testing. you killed me so...."